# initialize structure members using pointer in c++

Tags: c++, struct, g++

i am writing a simple c++ code to initialize members of a structure using g++ in codeblocks. the following code compiles without any errors or warnings, but when i run the code, i am getting an error

> try.exe has stopped working.

i think the problem occurs when i am assigning value to the integer member val.

```
#include<iostream>

struct node{
  int val;
  node *next;
}*head;

int main(){
  head->val=10;
  std::cout<<head->val;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *p=NULL; *p = 1;` compiles without errors too, and like this code, is similarly walking into **undefined behavior**. `head` needs to point to valid memory before you can dereference it and start storing data within. As-written, it is *indeterminate*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`head` is an uninitialised pointer.  The location it points to is undefined but likely isn't writeable by your code, causing a crash when you try to write to it in the line `head->val=10;`

To fix this, you need to allocate memory for `head`

```
head = new node();
head->val=10;
....
delete head;
```

Alternatively, you don't actually need the pointer in your example

```
struct node{
  int val;
  node *next;
}head;

int main(){
  head.val=10;
  std::cout<<head.val;
```

Comment: + we came same time :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks. I'll defer to your answer next time round :)